# EF Core ValueObject comparison could not be translated in Where operator

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository, domain-driven-design

I have designed my domain using DDD and EF Core 6.

Assuming my Firm Entity looks like this:

```
public class Firm : AggregateRoot
{

    public VATNumber vatNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected Firm() { }

    public static Firm Create(string name, string vatNumber) {
        ...
    }          
}
```

And my VATNumber ValueObject looks like this:

```
public class VATNumber : ValueObject
{
    public string Value { get; } = default!;

    private VATNumber()
    {
    }

    public static VATNumber Create(string value)
    {
       ...
    }

    public static implicit operator string(VATNumber vatNumber) => vatNumber.Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

I get data from Repository using such query:

```
public List<Firm> GetByVATNumber(string vatNumber)
{
    return _context.Firms
                .Where(f => f.VATNumber.Value == vatNumber)
                .ToList();
}
```

When I launch the query, I have this exception :

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor|The
> LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .Where(f => f.VATNumber.Value ==
> __vatNumber_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList',
> or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information.

I have already setup a conversion for VATNumber parameter, like this one:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Firm>()
       .Property(f => f.VATNumber)
           .HasMaxLength(50)
           .HasConversion(
               vatNumber => vatNumber.Value,
               value => VATNumber.Create(value))
           .IsRequired();

    // var converter = new ValueConverter<VATNumber, string>(
    //     vatNumber => vatNumber.Value,
    //     value => VATNumber.Create(value));
    // 
    // modelBuilder.Entity<Firm>().OwnsOne(f => f.VATNumber, f =>
    // {
    //     f.Property(p => p.Value)
    //         .HasColumnName(nameof(VATNumber))
    //         .HasMaxLength(50)
    //         // .HasConversion(converter) // I can't use HasConversion to convert from provider the VATNumber
    //         .IsRequired();
    // });
```

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this error ?

Thanks,

Romain

Comment: If you set up a converter, you can `.Where(f => f.VATNumber == VATNumber.Create(vatNumber))`

Comment: Maybe need to prepare `VATNumber.Create(vatNumber)` in a variable before. Not sure.

Comment: Yes `.Where(f => f.VATNumber == VATNumber.Create(vatNumber))` works. But I'd prefer try to use the other syntax (not create a other VATNumber instance).

Comment: Maybe you need modify the method defintion to `public List<Firm> GetByVATNumber(VATNumbervatNumber)` to respect the value object principe.

Comment: You want to said `.Where(f => f.VATNumber == VATNumber.Create(vatNumber))` is a better principe to respect the DDD Value Object ?

Comment: The main principle with value object, is to avoid primitive types that have no meaning. For exemple the method `GetByVATNumber` accept a string that can be a VAT number or other thing like a email. I suggest you modify the method so that it only accepts a VAT number. See my precedent comment.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I agree with you. I do that in most case. But in a exceptionnel case I would still like use theses two syntaxes :
`.Where(f => f.VATNumber == vatNumber)` and `.Where(f => f.VATNumber.Value == vatNumberString)`

Comment: Either way, EF Core don't accept this syntax. You're going to have to compromise. Maybe two method `GetByVATNumber`? one that accept `VATNumber` and one that accept `string` and call the one that accept `VATNumber`.